# Can't build flutter app on android Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, flutter

```
   * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    > Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
       > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
          > Failed to transform arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-54a7145303f0dd9d0f93424a2e124eb4abef5091.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-54a7145303f0dd9d0f93424a2e124eb4abef5091) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
             > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/alisinancobani/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-54a7145303f0dd9d0f93424a2e124eb4abef5091/17f3c0ac3e0e5cdc13df2596bac1d5e83834815d/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-54a7145303f0dd9d0f93424a2e124eb4abef5091.jar.
                > Java heap space
```

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.4, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale
en-TR)
• Flutter version 3.16.4 on channel stable at
/Users/alisinancobani/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 2e9cb0aa71 (2 days ago), 2023-12-11 14:35:13 -0700
• Engine revision 54a7145303
• Dart version 3.2.3
• DevTools version 2.28.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/alisinancobani/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Users/alisinancobani/Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15A507
• CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
• Android Studio at /Users/alisinancobani/Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.2.5)
• IntelliJ at /Users/alisinancobani/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
• Flutter plugin version 76.3.4
• Dart plugin version 232.10248